# How to call an Acumatica process through API

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a process in Acumatica: Release Production Orders

From the screen I can select a list of orders and release them

Is it possible to call that through an API (Web Service Endpoints)?

I know I can invoke it on each single like this `InvokeAsync(productionOrder, new ReleaseProductionOrder())` but I want to pass in a list of orders and process them

Comment: Are you using the contract based SOAP Api? or the Acumatica REST API client library?

Comment: Contract based SOAP Api

Comment: Not super helpful, but if this is new development, I would use the contract based REST API, Acumatica will deprecate SOAP in about I year I believe.. There is a helpful article on how to filter items in a processing view using the REST API here:

https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=2a697d48-0adf-4fa6-b5e5-af1f9459ec59

Comment: Tnx, actually working on migrating rest so above is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the Rest API. It is surprisingly easy to set up.

Find a list of the Webservice endpoints here:
[Instance Name]/Main?ScreenId=SM2070PL

I assume you are using Production Orders from the Manufacturing module.
/entity/MANUFACTURING/21.200.001/ProductionOrder

Rest API requests come with a general format: login, do some action, logout

**Login**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "INSTANCE NAME/entity/auth/login");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
var content = new StringContent("{  \"tenant\": \"YOUR TENANT\", \"name\": \"LOGINNAME\",  \"password\": \"LOGINPASSWORD",  \"branch\": \"BRANCH\"}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

> From the screen I can select a list of orders and release them

Send your orders one by one through:
I'm not familiar with the Manufacturing module. I am assuming ProductionOrderID is the only key field for a Production Order?

**Release Order**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "INSTANCE NAME/entity/MANUFACTURING/21.200.001/ProductionOrder?$filter=ProductionOrder%20eq%20'12345'/ReleaseProductionOrder");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
var content = new StringContent("{\r\n    \"ProductionOrder\" : {\"value\": \"12345\"},\r\n    \"Hold\" : {\"value\": false}\r\n}\r\n", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

**Logout**

Same request as Login but to the endpoint

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "INSTANCE NAME/entity/auth/logout");
```